# Improving performance while zooming on multiple components with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, performance, zooming

**Problem:** the zoom feature in my React app slows to a crawl when I have ~ >20 components rendered. My app needs to be able to support zoom with 1,000s of rendered components.

**Current implementation of zoom:**

Currently in my app I have a parent component that has a zoom feature which listens for the `onWheel` event and updates a `zoomFactor` variable using the `useState` hook.

Each child of this parent accesses the `zoomFactor` using `useContext`, so whenever the `zoomFactor` changes, the child component receives this change and updates its relevant dimensions (which in my case are an `offsetX` and `width`) by multiplying their original `offsetX` and `width` by the updated `zoomFactor` to yield a `zoomAdjustedOffsetX` and `zoomAdjustedWidth`.

Finally, these zoomAdjusted values are included in a styles object:

```
const styles = {
    transform: 'translateX(' + zoomAdjustedOffsetX + 'px)',
    width: zoomAdjustedWidth + 'px',
}
```

which is passed inline to the returned component.

I'm pretty sure the performance issue stems from the fact that I'm re-rendering all of these components during every step of the zoom. I don't *need* to re-render the components though, I just need to update two properties of their CSS during the onWheel event to accurately reflect the updated `zoomFactor`.

Therefore, **my current idea on how to fix the performance issues:**

1. Maintain a ref in my parent component to an object that maps the `ID` of every child component to a `ref` of that respective child component.
2. During the `onWheel` event, iterate through said map and "manually" update the CSS of each child component with the new `zoomFactor`.

I'm aware this isn't the proper "React way" of doing things, but I can't think of another way to  accomplish my goal of achieving the zoom effect by updating the CSS for each component without slowing my app to a crawl re-rendering everything.

**My question**: would this approach yield performance benefits? Can you think of any other strategies to manipulate the CSS of 1000's of components during an `onWheel` event in order to achieve a 'zooming' effect?

Answer (score 0):

Updating `width` is the killer here. The only really fast CSS properties to update are [`transform` and `opacity`](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/). Can you achieve what you want using `transform: scale` instead?

The next thing to look at would be debouncing the event. `onWheel` fires many times per frame, but you only need to render once per frame.

You might also get a small benefit from setting `will-change` and `contain: layout` in CSS.

If it's still slow after all that, you might think about avoiding a React update, like you mentioned. You could achieve this with [React-spring](https://www.react-spring.io/) instead of rolling your own system.